# How to force content editor not to cut my html code?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have the following problem while trying to integrate Lightbox and SPS2010. All done with scripts and styles and it really works.

I create new list element and write code in internal text editor in HTML mode:

```
<a href="/SiteAssets/faq/error01/err_01_02.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" title="My caption">image #1</a>
```

after saving my code enternal editor parse it and cut out `data-lightbox="image-1"` so i get only `<a href="/SiteAssets/faq/error01/err_01_02.jpg" title="My caption">image #1</a>`

Is there any possibility to avoid parsing? Or aletrnative variant to achive my goal, e.g. template or smthng else?

Whan i put my code in master page under logo lightbox works perfectly.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: I'm am thinking about changing internal text editor to other one, e.g. tiny mice. M.b. it will solve my problem? Or there is easier way?

Comment: My problem is solved: "For you long time Lightbox users, don't fret, you can still enable Lightbox by using rel="lightbox". The new data-lightbox approach is preferred though as it is valid html." rel="lightbox" instead of data-lightbox="image-1" really works. But question still remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a text file with the html content you want to add (in your case `<a href="SiteAssets/..`)
Upload this file somewhere onto your sharepoint site (for example into SiteAssets library).
Go to content editor webpart, edit it and in "Content Link" section add a url to your text file.
Remove all text from internat text editor.
Save and problem solved, content editor will not change anything in your text file and will always load its content as required.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Such simple task makes me feel like pervert, when I use SPS.

Answer (score 0):

The content editor is notorious for stripping out markup it doesn't like. Put markup in external file.